# What are some cost-effective options for a one-time large import of sorted data to Dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, amazon-dynamodb

I want to quickly (less than a day) import 1 billion records into DynamoDB, yet when I try importing these records via Hive and EMR as [one tutorial recommended](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb/), the job makes no progress with write-throughput="72" and using 3 cc3.8xlarge EMR slaves (i.e. at 0% after 1 hour).

This slowness is apparently [a common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683136/amazon-elastic-mapreduce-mass-insert-from-s3-to-dynamodb-is-incredibly-slow) as another SO user noted, and Amazon's recommendation is to temporarily have a large write-throughput, so this is one option I'm considering.  However, a commenter on that post mentioned that sorted data causes an IO bottleneck, which is the situation I'm facing (data was generated by Hadoop, and thus each of my input files are sorted).

Newer documentation on importing recommends using a Amazon Data Pipeline (although my first test with this failed with errors from Hive about processing rows with null values (e.g. 'Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"item":{*<one of my keys>*:null}}'). I'm not sure if my data has null rows or if the issue is my schema doesn't match with the Data Pipeline's expected format.  (***Edit:*** just noticed in documentation, *"The file must be in a folder with the same name as your table, and the file must be named using the following format: YYYY-MM-DD_HH.MM."*, so I will try again with this format).  In any case, I assume this is just making the above-described Hive importing easier to use, and that it would be prone to the same slowness I found with my manually-created EMR->Hive->DynamoDB import job.

I also see there is a somewhat newer (i.e. 2012) [BatchWriteItem API call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) that might be worth checking out.  I'd like to avoid writing a custom MapReduce job to do this importing, but will do it if I have to.

Actual questions:

- What import method are others having success with to get their data into DynamoDB?
- If I increase my write-throughput to some high value like 10,000 -- which "will cost up to $4,836.10 per month if you have exceeded the free tier" -- and then reduce that number to 1 after the import finishes, will I be paying upwards of $4,000, or does the planned reduction after import avoid most of those charges (assuming my import finishes in a day or so)?
- Should I try shuffling my data so that the keys are no longer sorted -- thus helping avoid IO bottlenecks described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I increase my write-throughput to some high value like 10,000 -- which "will cost up to $4,836.10 per month if you have exceeded the free tier" -- and then reduce that number to 1 after the import finishes, will I be paying upwards of $4,000, or does the planned reduction after import avoid most of those charges (assuming my import finishes in a day or so)?

Throughput is billed in terms of provisioned throughput hours.  From the [pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/):

"Write Throughput: $0.0065 per hour for every 10 units of Write Capacity (enough capacity to do up to 36,000 writes per hour)*"

Another way to think of this, is that if you want to do 36,000 writes to DynamoDB in an hour, you can provision 10 write capacity units, and it will cost $0.0065.  If you dial down your provisioned throughput after than hour, then from then on you'll be charged for your lower provisioned throughput hourly rate.

Loading 1 billion items, assuming the items are <= 1 KB, will require 1 billion write capacity units.  The cost for doing this data load is very similar regardless of how quickly you load the data.  So if you drive 1,000 write capacity units per second, the data load will take around 12 days.  With 10,000, it will take 27 hours in the best case, assuming you can evenly drive that throughput.  Even 2 days of a table with 10,000 write capacity units provisioned will cost around $312 for the write throughput.  (10,000 writes = $0.0065 * 1000 = $6.5 per hour, * 48 hours = $312).

> Should I try shuffling my data so that the keys are no longer sorted -- thus helping avoid IO bottlenecks described above?

That would probably help, yes.  But how many "range keys" per "hash key" on average and in the worst-case?  Some amount of unevenness is probably not going to be noticeable.  I could imagine a process for shuffling the data where in EMR, you add a column and populate it with a random number for each row, and then sort by that.  I haven't tried this, however.

> Newer documentation on importing recommends using a Amazon Data Pipeline

Data Pipeline is provisioning an EMR cluster for you under the hood, so you may want to stick to using your own EMR setup to have full control over your record format, and possibly also using EMR to do the shuffling you were talking about.

> I also see there is a somewhat newer (i.e. 2012) BatchWriteItem API call

Ultimately this is what the EMR code is already doing under the hood (you can see the metrics about the number of BatchWriteItem calls against your table in the CloudWatch metrics DynamoDB emits).